# Does this mean I should show $L(x)$ is well-defined?

Tags: real-analysis

I need to show that $L(x) = \int^x_1 \frac{1}{t} \ dt$ is a function $L:(0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$.

Do I just need to say that if $x = y$, then $L(x) = L(y)$ for $x,y \in (0,\infty)$? I'm not sure what this is asking exactly. Any help?

Comment: I would guess that you need to prove that the integral exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We must show that the integral exists. Notice that the function $f(t) = \frac{1}{t}$ is continuous on $ (0,+\infty)$ and is therefore also continuous on $[1,x]$ ($x>1$) and $[x,1]$ for $1 > x > 0$. Since $f$ is continuous on $[1,x]$, $[x,1]$ it is also Riemann-integrable on $[1,x]$, $[x,1]$  and the function 
$$ L : \mathbb{R}_0^+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R} : x \mapsto \int_1^x \frac{1}{t} dt $$
is well defined.